# Optimized Query - INTO command with UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server

Are there performance differences between the two queries below that do the same thing but written slightly differently?  If there are no performance issue, is one way more generally accepted than another? **Thanks in advance!**

```
Select * 
into #temp
FROM ( 
   Select * from table1
    UNION 
   select * from table2
    UNION 
   select * from table3 
)
```

**VS**

```
Select * 
into #temp
FROM table1 
UNION
select * 
FROM table2
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM table3
```

Comment: Did you see a performance difference when you tested these two queries out? Any difference in run time or reads?

Comment: Look at the execution plans for each query.

Comment: I'd expect the execution plans to be *identical*.  But the first is simpler to read and understand.

Comment: if I'm able to check the performance myself, then I wouldn't be posting about it.  thank you for the responses

Comment: You can check the performance yourself, but perhaps you don't know how. You can look at the execution plan an analyze what they are doing. If you don't know how to do that there are lots and lots of articles posted about this all over the place.

Comment: This forum and the users are so helpful.  I have nothing but love for the people that take time out of their day to assist on questions.   

Personally, I have a million other things going on at work, and 2 million off work.  Some stuff fall thru the cracks and I won't have the time or patience to research it.  I'm not a regular poster and only post when deadlines are near and stress is high.   This post falls in that category.

thanks everybody's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, performance will depend on which version, service pack of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: since my ask privileges are gone, my understanding is the question being asked is too simple of a question for this forum.  This question helped me, and if it helped me, then it'll help others like me.    Sometimes, formulating the question takes longer than the amount of time and effort it takes a skilled SME to read, understand, and provide feedback.  What's giving this question -3?  Fact that elitist SMEs believe data scientists need to understand sql execution plans?  Or maybe the formatting was off? or the question header is awkward?